# How to make menu item with popover dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

If there is no experience data which I found by jquery I want to show a popover object on the nav menu (li object); which is data-content field data-content="Experience is empty" of "a" tag in the nav menu .

nav menu :

```
<div class="span3 ozgecmis-sidebar">
    <ul class="nav nav-list ozgecmis-sidenav" id="ozgecmis-nav"> 
        <li><a href="#ogrenim" class="section-link">Öğrenim Bilgileri</a></li>
        <li><a href="#meslek" class="section-link">Meslek Bilgileri</a></li>                     
        <li id="experience" runat="server" ><a href="#exp" class="section-link" >Work Experience</a></li>                        
    </ul>        
</div>
```

if there is no experience data the menu item will be

```
<div class="span3 ozgecmis-sidebar">  
    <ul class="nav nav-list ozgecmis-sidenav" id="ozgecmis-nav">
        <li><a href="#ogrenim" class="section-link">Öğrenim Bilgileri</a></li>
        <li><a href="#meslek" class="section-link">Meslek Bilgileri</a></li>     
        <li id="experience" runat="server"  style="background-color:pink;"><a class="popover-link-a section-link" href="#exp" data-toggle="popover" title="Work experience" data-content="Work Exp is empty !" onclick="javascript:return false;">Work experience</a>        
        </li>
    </ul> 
</div>
```

if there is experience data the menu item will be

```
<div class="span3 ozgecmis-sidebar">
    <ul class="nav nav-list ozgecmis-sidenav" id="ozgecmis-nav"> 
        <li><a href="#ogrenim" class="section-link">Öğrenim Bilgileri</a></li>
        <li><a href="#meslek" class="section-link">Meslek Bilgileri</a></li>       
        <li id="experience" runat="server" ><a href="#exp" class="section-link">Work Experience</a></li>
    </ul> 
</div>
```

The code where I make menu with popover is as follows:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var gridView = document.getElementById("ctl03_gridExperience");
    var rows = gridView.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    if (rows.length == 0) {
       document.querySelectorAll("a.section-link").forEach((item) => {
       if (item.innerText == 'Work Experience'){
           item.classList.add('popover-link-a');
       }
    }); 
  }                         
  }                  
  });
  </script>
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the attributes if not needed

No need to loop over `a.section-link` since you can access the experience link directly using `document.querySelector("#experience a");`

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const experience = document.querySelector("ctl03_gridExperience tr");
  const exLink = document.querySelector("#experience a");
  if (experience) {
    ["toggle", "content"].forEach(attr => delete exLink.dataset[attr]);
    exLink.classList.remove("popover-link-a");
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="span3 ozgecmis-sidebar">
  <ul class="nav nav-list ozgecmis-sidenav" id="ozgecmis-nav">
    <li id="experience" runat="server" style="background-color:pink;">
      <a class="popover-link-a section-link" href="#experience" data-toggle="popover" title="Work experience" data-content="Work Exp is empty !">Work experience</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't `forEach` loop?

Comment: No need to loop over `a.section-link`

Comment: need to loop over a.section-link because there are different li menus

Comment: Please post a [mcve] with at least 2 or 3 complete examples so we can see. You have multiple identical IDs if what you say is correct.

Comment: I revised the situation

Comment: So I repeat: No need to loop. I access the link in the LI with ID experience